# 7-zip extracted files not showing up when called from command line

Tags: command-line, 7zip

I am attempting to write a command that calls 7-zip from the command line.  My command is:

7z x z:\dev\archive.7z

Anytime I run this command in the command prompt, it acts like it's working, but when I navigate to the folder after the fact, the extracted files aren't there, although they are there if I run 7-zip from the contextual menu.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What is your current directory when you run the command?

Comment: C:\Users\myusername.  As soon as I saw the question, I took a look in that directory, and my files were there.  However, I'm trying to redo the command by specifying a destination folder, and now it's saying there are no files to process.

Comment: Specifying a destination folder is the right approach. What command have you tried?

Comment: 7z x z:\dev\archive.7z z:\dev  I've also tried using the -spf switch as one of the commenters suggested.

Comment: Check out my answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a destination directory, 7z will extract files in your current directory.

As per the doc, to specify a target:

```
7z x archive.zip -oC:\path\to\target
```

Or use `cd C:\path\to\target` and then invoke your initial command.

In your case (from comments), what you want is:

```
7z x z:\dev\archive.7z -oz:\dev
```

[This nice answer](https://superuser.com/a/914538) might help if you're confused with the options.

Comment: Thank you!  The -o switch did it. :-)

Comment: [Please check this quick read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for next time

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -spf switch

7z x z:\dev\archive.7z -spf